# AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'home'

Tags: python, django

Learning from a Udemy course I am taking by Nick Walter on Django, I am writing my own “Credit Card Redaction” app. The basic functionality is in place. But now I am trying to add a blog post app to go with it.   I successfully initiated the app using `$ python3 manage.py startapp posts`. But as soon as I started filling in the urls.py, template and sub-views, my server has stopped running. I get:

> File "/home//dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/CC_Redact/urls.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
> url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
> ```
>
> AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'home'

This is Django 2.0 with Python 3.6 using the built in test server (no where near production environment yet). I’m running my code inside an activated virtual environment. These are the contents of my requirements.txt:

> Django==2.0.13
>
> Pillow==5.4.1
>
> psycopg2==2.7.7
>
> psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
>
> pytz==2018.9

Pretty basic, right?

**urls.py** in my primary project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from posts import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^result/', views.result, name='result'),
    url(r'^james/', views.posts, name='james'),
```

**views.py** (in app folder):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def james(request):
    return render(request, 'posts/james.html')
```

As you can see, I've named my function "james", as well as my template.

Here is **posts/templates/posts/james.html**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def james(request):
    return render(request, 'posts/james.html')
```

Finally, here is my file tree and directory structure: [image: file tree].

When running the sever, I am expecting to see "You are in James' posts!" in bold text when navigating to localhost:8000/posts. Instead I am receiving:

```
python manage.py runserver     
Performing system checks...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f41c70286a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/<user>/dev/projects/python/2018-and-2019/CC_Redact/CC_Redact/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'home'
```

edit: btw: [Here is my project on GitHub](https://github.com/Angeles4four/CC_Redact). I am accepting pull requests.

Comment: You have no view named `home` ; replace `def james(request)` by `def home(request)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to focus more on the course. 
view.posts refers there is a def with name posts call that def.
In short view.posts calls posts def in view.

Change

```
def James(request):
```

To

`def posts(request)`:

In view.py
U also need to have a def with name "home"

Comment: I changed `def james(request):` to `def posts(request):`.  Now my interpreter is saying: `AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'home'` I think this new issue is related to the importing of views in urls.py.  I tried swapping these two lines around which didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Make a def in views.py with name home.

Comment: As I said earlier views.posts calls posts def in views.py similarly views.home will call home def in views.py which doesn't exists yet

Comment: By defining both the `home` and `result` function inside posts.views, my server runs successfully now. I've pushed these changes up to my GitHub repo with the link updated above. Thank you for your advice so far. However these functions already exist inside a separate views.py, as you can see in my file tree image above. So now my `home` and `result` functions exist in two separate views.py's, which is redundant. How could I re-write my urls.py to keep the two functions as they appear in the original views.py?